# How could I understand samplemask in OpenGL ES spec?

Tags: opengl-es

I was reading gles spec about samplemask.

There is a paragraph about samplemask I couldn't understand. Below is the snippet from the spec.

> When state specifies multiple fragment
>   shader invocations for a given fragment, the sample mask for any single fragment
>   shader invocation may specify a subset of the covered samples for the fragment. In
>   this case, the bit corresponding to each covered sample will be set in exactly one
>   fragment shader invocation.

Can someone help give me an example or help me understand it? I'm quite confused with the part "a subset of the covered samples for the fragment"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample mask (also called a coverage mask) defines which samples in the pixel are inside the primitive being rasterized, and which have survived any early ZS testing. This doesn't mean much if you only have one sample per pixel (you either render the fragment or not), but if you are using multi-sampling you will have multiple sample points per pixel. On the edge of a triangle rasterization might hit only 3 of 4 samples and have a coverage mask of `b0111`, which indicates which samples to write into the framebuffer.

For multi-sample anti-aliasing you only execute one fragment shader invocation per pixel, irrespective of the coverage mask, so that fragment will have (in our example) a coverage mask of `b0111`.

If you are using sample-rate shading in OpenGL ES 3.x you will execute three fragment shader invocations, one for each sample hit, so they will have the coverage mask `b0001`, `b0010` and `b0100`, each writing to one sub-pixel sample in the pixel with a unique fragment color.

Comment: thanks for your answer, for the part "When state specifies multiple fragment shader invocations for a given fragment", does this mean when sampleshading is enabled, and for a given fragment if 3 of 4 samples are hit after rasterization, the "multiple fragment shader invocations" means 3 invocations for each sample? And if I have below definition in fragment shader. `fs_out_color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`. This will write 1.0 for each sample?

Comment: You'll only ever have a maximum of one invocation per sample, but with MSAA you'll have multiple samples per pixel, so may have multiple invocations per pixel if you have sample-rate shading enabled AND a multi-sampled framebuffer.